# Dynamically lookup and get average using arrayformula

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying to get the average of all rows containing data in my `SourceSheet`, which need to be matched with the Fish ID `A1:F1` in `Sheet1` and `A2:A5` in `SourceSheet`. I want to do this by using `ARRAYFORMULA()` since `Sheet1!A2:A5` is dynamic and may contain other values from time to time.

So far, I've only managed the lookup-and-average-part by:

`=AVERAGE(ARRAYFORMULA(HLOOKUP($A2,SourceSheet!A:F,ROW(Items!A$2:F),FALSE)))`

How do i achieve the result (see below) with out copying this formula down all rows? Thanks in advance!

Source Data (`SourceSheet`)

`+------+--------+-----+--------+---------+---------+
| tuna | mullet | cod | salmon | herring | catfish |
+------+--------+-----+--------+---------+---------+
|    4 |      3 |   5 |      5 |       5 |       3 |
|    5 |      3 |   3 |      1 |       3 |       2 |
|    5 |      4 |   4 |      4 |       4 |       4 |
|    1 |      2 |   1 |      2 |       3 |       1 |
|    3 |      2 |   2 |      2 |       3 |       2 |
|    4 |      2 |   4 |      2 |       3 |       3 |
|    4 |      2 |   2 |      1 |       2 |       1 |
|    4 |      3 |   4 |      3 |       5 |       4 |
|    3 |      4 |   4 |      2 |       5 |       1 |
|    4 |      3 |   4 |      1 |       2 |       2 |
|    2 |      1 |   3 |      1 |       1 |       1 |
|    2 |      4 |   3 |      2 |       2 |       2 |
|    5 |      3 |   5 |      4 |       5 |       2 |
|    4 |      2 |   4 |      2 |       3 |       2 |
|    2 |      4 |   4 |      3 |       4 |       2 |
|    5 |      4 |   5 |      5 |       3 |       2 |
|    3 |      1 |   3 |      3 |       4 |       2 |
+------+--------+-----+--------+---------+---------+`

What I'm trying to achieve: (`Sheet1`)

`+---------+---------+
|         | Average |
+---------+---------+
| mullet  | 2.76    |
| salmon  | 2.75    |
| herring | 2.73    |
| catfish | 2.64    |
+---------+---------+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Formula

```
=ArrayFormula(
MMULT(
hlookup(A2:A5,SourceSheet!A:F,
TRANSPOSE(FILTER(ROW(SourceSheet!A2:A),LEN(SourceSheet!A2:A))),FALSE),
n(ISNUMBER((FILTER(ROW(SourceSheet!A2:A),LEN(SourceSheet!A2:A)))))
)
/
count(SourceSheet!A2:A)
)
```

## Explanation

AVERAGE is an aggregate function. It could take several values separated by commas, one array or several arrays of values as arguments and returns a single value. This kind of functions if are used on an array formulas will return a single value, so when it's require to return an array of values it's required to use other methods.

In this case, MMULT is used to return the sum of values of each row.

## See also

- [Using CHOOSE and CONCATENATE with ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165717/using-choose-and-concatenate-with-arrayformula-in-google-sheets)

Comment: This works! Thank you! Although, I must say I don't understand MMULT() very well.

Comment: A follow up question, if you may: Is it possible to achieve this using the average-formula as well? I've got some more parameters I need to calculate, like i.e. STDEV() and eventually it will be a challenge to make the current formula work with those

Comment: I added an explanation. Regarding the follow up question, please post it as a new question.